# str_replace is replacing all but 1 section of my string correctly.

Tags: php

My original string looks like this

> value='' tabindex='500'

I would like to replace the string with this

> value='Email:' tabindex='500' onclick=\"if (this.value=='Email:') {this.value='';}

So I use this str_replace function

```
$userForm = str_replace("value='' tabindex='500'", "value='Email:' tabindex='500' onclick=\"if (this.value=='Email:') {this.value='';}\"",$userForm);
```

My output ends up being this

```
value="" tabindex="500" onfocus=" if (this.value == '') { this.value = ''; }"
```

If you notice, everything except for the parts that include 'value="Email:" are replaced correctly...

I was hoping someone might have an idea on why this is happening? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can use the `placeholder` attribute in html and it does basically the same thing you're trying to do with javascript (i.e. show 'Email:' on input field and automatically erase as user begins to type). I haven't seen someone try to do what you're doing here in javascript in over 6 years.

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for something like:

```
$userForm = preg_replace('/value=\'\' tabindex=\'(.*?)\'/i', 'value=\'Email:\' tabindex=\'$1\' onclick="if (this.value==\'Email:\') {this.value=\'\';}', $userForm);
```

---

**Result:**

```
value='Email:' tabindex='500' onclick="if (this.value=='Email:') {this.value='';}
```

---

[preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: I'm not saying your answer is wrong, on the contrary. But OP question was *I was hoping someone might have an idea on why this is happening?* and I legitimately am curious about its reasons. Do you know anything about it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below codes:

```
$val = "value='' tabindex='500'";

$result = str_replace( "value='' tabindex='500'", "value='Email:' tabindex='500' onclick=" . '\"if' . " (this.value=='Email:') {this.value='';}", $val );

echo $result;
```

Comment: ... which is essentially the **exact same code** OP used and claimed to be failing, except that you didn't escaped the last double quote (actually you deleted it)

Comment: but I got this result after running: `value='Email:' tabindex='500' onclick="if (this.value=='Email:') {this.value='';}`

Comment: Without the trailing double quote.

Comment: There is ***still*** no difference. Can you explain exactly *what* did you fix in OP code?

Answer (score 0):

Something is missing here, copying your code right off:

```
<?php

$userForm = "value='' tabindex='500'";

var_dump($userForm);

echo '<br><br>';

$userForm = str_replace("value='' tabindex='500'", "value='Email:' tabindex='500' onclick=\"if (this.value=='Email:') {this.value='';}\"",$userForm);

var_dump($userForm);
```

I end up with the following result:

```
value='Email:' tabindex='500' onclick="if (this.value=='Email:') {this.value='';}"
```

which seems to be the results you are looking for. Do you alter the variable anywhere else?